# Babel doesn't run from npm script

Tags: npm, babeljs

I have the babel cli installed on my machine using:

```
npm install -g babel-cli
```

When I run this command I get the desired output. i.e `out.js` is created

```
babel script.js --out-file out.js
```

but when I try to run that command via `npm` I get an error saying

```
The CLI has been moved into the package `babel-cli`.

$ npm install -g babel-cli
```

Here's the package.json:

```
{
    "name": "youtubeapiloader",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
    "compile": "babel -g src/youtube-api-loader.js --out-file   youtube-api.js",
    "prepublish": "npm run compile"
},
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel": "^6.1.18"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried installing `babel-cli` as a *devDependency* already?
I managed to get it working like this. Just do

```
npm install babel-cli --save-dev
```

Perhaps you might also need `babel-core`, but I can not remember correctly.

Note that if you want to run this using **Travis CI** you might still need to globally install babel-cli using a custom installation step within your *.travis.yml*. e.g.

```
language: node_js
sudo: false
node_js:
  - "5.0"
install:
  - npm install -g babel-cli
  - npm install
```

Comment: You can also reference the local babel binary instead of installing it globally: `./node_modules/.bin/babel`